# Octave handle class method returns object instead of number

Tags: oop, octave

I have a class `TestClass`:

```
classdef TestClass < handle
  methods
    function o = doNothing(vec)
      o = vec;
    end
  end
end
```

I run the `doNothing` method like this:

```
test = TestClass;
x = test.doNothing([1, 0, 1]);
```

I would expect `x` to contain `[1, 0, 1]` after executing this code but for some reason `doNothing` returns `TestClass` object.

I'm very new to Octave / Matlab so my question can be result of fundamental misunderstanding, however I wasn't able to find answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first input to an object method is an instance of itself, so in your sample code `vec` is your `TestClass` object. Since Octave doesn't error on too many input arguments (at least for classes), you won't receive an error.

To fix this, add the self input to your method declaration:

```
classdef TestClass < handle
  methods
    function o = doNothing(self, vec)
      o = vec;
    end
  end
end
```

Which functions as expected:

```
>> A = TestClass;
>> A.doNothing(12)

ans =  12
```